# How can the className return the wrong thing to me?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, debugging

So I think I'm going mad. I'm running this simple code to print a div and that div's class name.

```
 let popover = document.getElementsByClassName('popover inner');

 for(let i=0; i<popover.length; i++){
      let test = popover[i] as HTMLElement;
      console.log(test);
      console.log(test.className);
```

After this is printed I can see that one .className returns a different classname than the one I can see in entire div that was printed above it?

```
<div class="popover inner" </div>
popover inner do-hide
```

This is the result of the faulty iteration. This is the only div that does not have the "do-hide" suffix and the other prints during the execution look right.

What is happening here? Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: attributes do not get updated

Comment: @epascarello They don't? Is there a way to force an update? Or some other way to distinguish between these different divs?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well I'm trying to find the div that doesn't have the "do-hide" so I then can read some information from it.

Comment: @JohnSlaine `getElementsByClassName` finds any element that *have* all the specified classes (usually, only one is passed). Not the elements that have *exactly* the specified classes only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelector and not to find the element that does not have the class.

```js
document.querySelector(".popover:not(.do-hide)").classList.add("do-hide")
```

```css
.do-hide {
  opacity: .2
}
```

```html
<div class="popover inner do-hide">A</div>
<div class="popover inner">B</div>
<div class="popover inner do-hide">C</div>
```